# Loss is not decreasing while training Keras Sequential Model

Tags: python, pandas, keras, classification

I'm creating a very simple 2 layer feed forward network but am finding that the loss is not updating at all. I have some ideas but I wanted to get additional feedback/guidance.

Details about the data:

X_train:
(336876, 158)

X_dev:
(42109, 158)

Y_train counts:

```
0    285793
1     51083
Name: default, dtype: int64
```

Y_dev counts:

```
0    35724
1     6385
Name: default, dtype: int64
```

And here is my model architecture:

```
# define the architecture of the network
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], init="uniform", activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(3print("[INFO] compiling model...")

adam = Adam(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=adam,
    metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array(Y_train), epochs=12, batch_size=128,  verbose=1)Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

Now, with this, my loss after the first few epochs are as follows:

```
Epoch 1/12
336876/336876 [==============================] - 8s - loss: 2.4441 - acc: 0.8484     
Epoch 2/12
336876/336876 [==============================] - 7s - loss: 2.4441 - acc: 0.8484     
Epoch 3/12
336876/336876 [==============================] - 6s - loss: 2.4441 - acc: 0.8484     
Epoch 4/12
336876/336876 [==============================] - 7s - loss: 2.4441 - acc: 0.8484     
Epoch 5/12
336876/336876 [==============================] - 7s - loss: 2.4441 - acc: 0.8484     
Epoch 6/12
336876/336876 [==============================] - 7s - loss: 2.4441 - acc: 0.8484     
Epoch 7/12
336876/336876 [==============================] - 7s - loss: 2.4441 - acc: 0.8484     
Epoch 8/12
336876/336876 [==============================] - 6s - loss: 2.4441 - acc: 0.8484     
Epoch 9/12
336876/336876 [==============================] - 6s - loss: 2.4441 - acc: 0.8484
```

And when I test the model after, my f1_score is 0. My main thought was that I may need more data but I'd still expect it to perform better than it is now on the test set. Could it be that it is overfitting? I added Dropout but no luck there either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

at first glance, I believe that your learning rate is too high. Also, please consider normalizing your data especially if different features have different ranges of values (look at [Scaling](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)). Also, please consider changing your layer activations depending on whether your labels are multi-class or not. Assuming your code is of this form (you seem to have some typos in problem description):

```
# define the architecture of the network
model = Sequential()
#also what is the init="uniform" argument? I did not find this in keras documentation, consider removing this.
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], init="uniform", 
activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')))
#a slightly more conservative learning rate, play around with this.
adam = Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=adam,
metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array(Y_train), epochs=12, batch_size=128,  
verbose=1)
```

This should lead the loss to converge. If not, please consider deepening your neural net (think about how many parameters you may need).

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the classification layer before compiling your model.

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
adam = Adam(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=adam,
    metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array(Y_train), epochs=12, batch_size=128, verbose=1)
```